# Repair partition table for disks in a RAID1 array

Tags: software-raid, raid-1

Here's my problem. I have several arrays. RAID1. I've scanned each drive that's part of an array with gdisk and it reports problems.

One array (2 drives) has a damaged GPT partition table and a protective MBR.
Another array (2 drives) has no partition table at all.

I'd like to fix these. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't have me off load the data (8TB worth) as I don't have the space anywhere.

Is it possible to break the array, fix the partition table of a drive, rebuild the array, break it again, fix the other drive, and then finally rebuild it, both drives having been fixed? Or will rebuilding the array also rebuild the partition table too?

I have enabled bitmaps so rebuilding is at least shortened.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 server and don't have a graphical interface so a command line option will be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking to accomplish this in the future, it cannot be done. If you have a RAID1 array with two drives with GPT partition tables

E.g.,

```
sba
sbb
```

And break it apart (let's push sba out and call it failed), alter one drive to use MBR (here it's sba), for example, and then re-assemble the array by re-adding `sba`, it will once again use `sbb`'s partition table (GPT) as it becomes part of the array.

The only solution is to break the array, offload the data, wipe both drives, repair the partition table (which essentially is starting again as it will destroy anything written to the drive), and then create a new array.

I'm sure someone more familiar with RAID and partition tables can explain the underlying mechanism in the superblock, etc. that is responsible for mirror every aspect of the drives, but in lay terms, each drive is an exact mirror, write down to the partition table.